# Only update fields that have formulas in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code:

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application


Private Sub Document_Open()
  Set App = Word.Application
  ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub

Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
  ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

This code updates all fields in a Word template automatically. My question is, can it be altered to only update fields that contain formulas? For example, getting the value of bookmark Sect1 when the field receiving the information contains {=SUM(Sect1A3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could do it.

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
  Set App = Word.Application
  UpdateSumFields
End Sub

Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
  UpdateSumFields
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateSumFields()
    Dim field As field

    For Each field In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If CStr(field.Code) Like "*=SUM(Sect1A3)*" Then
            field.Update
        End If
    Next field
End Sub
```

Put whatever in the `like` statement. I'm sure there is a better way to make it more reusable. Maybe use an array with multiple fields you would like to update in one goal.

Here's an example:

```
Private Sub UpdateFieldExtended()
    Dim field As field
    Dim fieldCodePattern(1 To 5) As String

    fieldCodePattern(1) = "=SUM"
    fieldCodePattern(2) = "TOC"
    fieldCodePattern(3) = "REF"
    fieldCodePattern(4) = "STYLEREF"
    fieldCodePattern(5) = "DATE"

    For Each field In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If IsInArray(CStr(field.Code), fieldCodePattern) Then
            field.Update
        End If
    Next field
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Trim(stringToBeFound) Like "*" + arr(i) + "*" Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```